# JQuery Show Element if Div Contain Number Greather Than XX

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I want to show `singlepostview` only if number inside `tptn_counter` is greather than 100.

```
<span class="singlepostview" title="Views">
<div class="tptn_counter" id="tptn_counter_6856">59</div>
</span>
```

I use:

```
if(jQuery(".tptn_counter").text() > 100 ) {
   jQuery(".singlepostview").show();
}
```

and I set CSS to:

```
.singlepostview {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    line-height: 41px;
    height: 41px;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}
```

The code works very well but when I have number with comma separator like 1,000 (one thousand), `singlepostview` keep hide. Whats wrong?

Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

```js
 if(jQuery(".tptn_counter").text() > 100 ) {
       jQuery(".singlepostview").show();
    }
```

```css
.singlepostview {
        position: relative;
     display: none;
     cursor: pointer;
        float: right;
        line-height: 41px;
        height: 41px;
        margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="singlepostview" title="Views">
    <div class="tptn_counter" id="tptn_counter_6856">1,000</div>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `jQuery(".tptn_counter").text().split(",").join("")` or `jQuery(".tptn_counter").text().replace(",","")` to remove `,` form text

```js
if(jQuery(".tptn_counter").text().split(",").join("") > 100 ) {
   jQuery(".singlepostview").show();
}
//OR 
//
//if(jQuery(".tptn_counter").text().replace(",","") > 100 ) {
//   jQuery(".singlepostview").show();
//}
```

```css
.singlepostview {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    line-height: 41px;
    height: 41px;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="singlepostview" title="Views">
<div class="tptn_counter" id="tptn_counter_6856">1,000</div>
</span>
```

Comment: you'r welcome please mark the answer as accepted answer if it helped @AnggriyawanNugrahaPrasetya